# Fourth Order Homogeneous Ordinary Differential Equation With Double Complex Conjugate Roots (2.10-14)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, roots

This is actually a problem in algebra as shall be seen. I need to find the general solution for the following differential equation:

$$y''''+8y''+16y=0$$

The characteristic equation for this is:

$$\lambda^4+8\lambda^2+16=0$$

Factoring out gives us:

$$(\lambda^2+4)^2=(\lambda^2+4)(\lambda^2+4)=0$$

This generates a set of double complex conjugate roots $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm i2$ and $\lambda_{3,4}=\pm i2$

The general solution I get is:

$$y=A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x)+xC\cos(2x)+xD\sin(2x)$$

Is this correct? If not please explain in detail where I went wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: Generally, we write $2i$ rather than $i2$.

Comment: If you want to check your answer, you could always plug each of the four basis solutions into the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is correct. Good job!

Comment: Thank you. It's all I needed to know. :)